# Access to object not working and return null

Tags: kotlin, singleton

I am trying to save data into a kotlin object but I feel that it's not working.

the object is

```
object User {
    var userInfo: UserInfo? = null
    var listOfVehicles: MutableList<Vehicle> = mutableListOf()

    init {}

    fun clear(){
        userInfo = null
        listOfVehicles = mutableListOf()
    }

}
```

and I would like to be able to access it from everywhere and be able to modify it from any activities, fragments....

to add a value inside, I just do : `User.userInfo.name = "blabla"` but it keep being null

any idea how to fix it ? I tried as well to use val user: User? = null but it's the same.

I want to have User a single data structure used by any part of the code to retrieve or add data.

What did I miss ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to make an assignment to userInfo, as `userInfo = UserInfo()`

Comment: Not sure how it would let you do that without a compiler error since `userInfo` is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the `userInfo` before assigning values to it.

```
object User {
    var userInfo: UserInfo? = UserInfo()
    var listOfVehicles: MutableList<Vehicle> = mutableListOf()

    init {
    }

    fun clear() {
        userInfo = null
        listOfVehicles = mutableListOf()
    }

}
```

Now to use this, `User.userInfo?.name = "blabla"`